# Memory defragmentation software. How does it work? Does it work?

Tags: memory, memory-management

I was reading an article on memory fragmentation when I recalled that there are several examples of software that claim to defragment memory. I got curious, how does it work? Does it work at all?

**EDIT:**
xappymah gave a good argument against memory defragmentation in that a process might be very surprised to learn that its memory layout suddenly changed. But as I see it there's still the possibility of the OS providing some sort of API for global memory control. It does seem a bit unlikely however since it would give rise to the possibility of using it in malicious intent, if badly designed. Does anyone know if there is an OS out there that supports something of the sort?

Comment: This is not offtopic - it's a very interesting question from software development standpoint. For me for example "memory defragmentation" sounds like BS (unless that's a managed environment) - I'd like to know whether it is really possible.

Comment: About your second question. I did some research and found that such APIs exist in modern OSs like Windows or Mac OSX (and else). But of course, the administrative (root) rights are required for using such functions, and inaccurate actions can really make a mess. (BTW, existing of such API in every OS is very logical though, because it is needed to the OS itself at least :) )

Comment: @xappymah: Thank you. I find this topic very interesting and I'll have to conduct some research myself to still my curiosity. I've accepted your original answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real memory defragmentation on a process level is possible only in managed environments such as, for example, Java VMs when you have some kind of an access to objects allocated in memory and can manage them.

But if we are talking about the unmanaged applications then there is no possibility to control their memory with third-party tools because every process (both the tool and the application) runs in its own address space and doesn't have access to another's one, at least without help from OS.
However even if you get access to another process's memory (by hacking your OS or else) and start modifying it I think the target application would be very "surprised". 
Just imagine, you allocated a chunk of memory, got it's starting address and on the next second this chunk of memory is moved somewhere else because of "VeryCoolMemoryDefragmenter" :)

Comment: +1, this makes sense, but what if those programs claim to do some other kind of defragmentation?

Comment: Well, those programs always can defragment their own memory :) Anyway, even if we are talking about memory optimization at all (not just defragmentation) there is no silver bullet. The best that mostly all programs, which are claiming they can "optimize memory", could do is just to flush all memory in the swap. The worst - infect your computer with some virus or just damage the system. So, unfortunately, every application has to manage its memory usage by itself.

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion memory it's a kind of Flash Drive, and this chip don't get fragmented because there aren't turning disks pins recording and playing information, in a random way, like a lie detector. This is the way that Hard Disk Fragmentation it's done. That's why SSD drives are so fast, effective, reliable and maintenance free. SSD it's a BIG piece of memory and it kind of look alike.